# Find all assignments that satisfy a set of clauses (cnf)

Tags: logic

I have a set of clauses, and there are 10 variables. The clauses look like this:

> (¬B ∨ C) ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬C) ∧ (¬D ∨ E) ....

So nothing that complicated, but there are 10 variables, so the truth table willl be pretty big. Is there a better way to find the assignments that satisfy this set of clauses, or do I have to brute force it?

Comment: Simplify the expression first.

Comment: So do all clauses contain exactly two literals?

Comment: Yes they do, there is 12 of them, no duplicates and nothing like (¬A ∨ A)

Answer (score 1):

The satisfiability problem is NP-complete in general; this is a foundational result in computational complexity theory. But in the case of formulae in 2-CNF (that is, every clause contains at most two literal s), the satisfiability problem is polynomial-time decidable. Your formula appears to be in 2-CNF. See e.g. https://www.google.dk/amp/s/kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/solving-2-sat-in-linear-time/amp/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easy method (a kind of Davis Putnam method) which will most likely be a good bit more efficient than going through all 1024 truth-value combinations:

Start

Let $C$ be your clause set

Loop:

If $C= \emptyset$, then the clause set is satisfiable. Stop.

If $\emptyset \in C$, then $C$ is not saisfiable. Stop.

If $\{ L \} \in C$ where $L$ is a literal (an atomic statement or the negation thereof; a clause that contains just one literal is called a *unit clause*), then reduce the clause set $C$ with regard to $L$. This means that you remove all clauses that contain $L$ from $C$, and remove the complement $L'$ of $L$ from any clause in which it occurs (the complement of $A$ is $\neg A$, and vice versa). Example: Reducing clause set $\{ \{ A, B \}, \{ \neg A, C \}, \{ D, E \}\}$ with regard to $A$ results in $\{ \{ C \}, \{D,E \} \}$). Repeat the loop.

If there is no unit clause, then simply pick any literal $L$ that occurs in $C$, and see if either $C$ reduced with regard to $L$ is satisfiable, or if $C$ with regard to $L'$ is satisfiable.